# Remove the bookmark bar in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I am wondering if there is any way to remove the bookmark bar (not sure what else it may be called) in TexStudio?

I have disabled the 'central' toolbar, but there is still a bar taking up quite a bit of space, that I don't use at all. It's functionallity appears to be to add bookmarks and access them quickly.

Here is a screenshot of version 2.12.16 of texstudio on windows 7, with text of my documents obfuscated, and the toolbar I am talking about highlighted in red.

[image]

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Well, perhaps you are lucky and here is someone knowing that, but your question is a pure TeXStudio question and I think that should be answered by the support or an perhaps existing mailing list to support that software? You also did not mention which version of Windows and which version of TeXStudio you are using. That could be important to solve your issue ...

Comment: Well I might look into posting there as well, but just posted here first. It doesn't seem to be off-topic to do so given numerous other questions in the same vein. Editing question to put in versions.

Comment: I don't think you can disable it. You can however make it much more useful by enabling line numbers. (Which will, of course, make it a bit wider.)

Comment: Ahh, I don't ant it wider at all, I want it gone :) I don't need line numbers when the line number is shown in the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you have to open the `Configure TeXstudio` menu, then go to the `Editor` section and uncheck the `Folding` option.

Comment: There is still a bar there but it is much thinner, so that's a plus! Thanks!